React pagination queries
I am building pagination for React project. The pagination itself does work when I click on prev or next page buttons, but I've got 2 problems, which I can't figure out.

Browser button acts weird. I am at home page (page1) and click next page until I reach last page(page3). Now I open specific product page while at page 3 and when I click browser back button first time it correctly puts me back into page 3, but when I click again I expect to go back to page 2, but instead I am moved out of the website entirely and see some other website which I was browsing before.

I also get this warning in chrome dev tools:

Use of history.pushState in a trivial session history context, which
maintains only one session history entry.

It seems like this warning indicated the problem, but how to save multiple history records?

If I manually change search query in browser from "http://localhost:5173/?p=1" let's say to "http://localhost:5173/?p=3" nothing happens. I see that the page refreshes and I believe my new "?p=3" query is not persisted somehow so useEffect code does not run?

Code:
let [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(getCurrentPage());
let [pagesCount, setPagesCount] = useState(0);
let [itemsCount, setItemsCount] = useState(0);
let [productData, UpdateProductData] = useState([]);
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

// On init
useEffect(() => {
  getCurrentPage();
  setSearchParams({ p: `${currentPage}` });
  calcPagesCount();
  getData();
}, []);

// Updates screen if query is changed by browser back button or manually changing query in url bar
useEffect(() => {
  let CurrentPageFromQuery: number;
  CurrentPageFromQuery = Number(location.search.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  setCurrentPage(CurrentPageFromQuery);
  saveCurrentPage();
  getData();
}, [searchParams]);

// Updates query if next/prev page buttons are clicked
useEffect(() => {
  saveCurrentPage();
  getData();
  setSearchParams({ p: `${currentPage}` });
}, [currentPage]);

function prevPage() {
  if (currentPage !== 1) {
    getCurrentPage();
    setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
    saveCurrentPage();
  }
}

function nextPage() {
  if (currentPage !== pagesCount) {
    getCurrentPage();
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    saveCurrentPage();
  }
}

function saveCurrentPage() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("current page", String(currentPage));
}

function getCurrentPage(): number {
  return Number(sessionStorage.getItem("current page") || 1);
}

async function calcPagesCount() {
  const api_url = `https://******&per_page=99`;
  const req = await fetch(api_url);
  const products = await req.json();
  setItemsCount(products.length);
  setPagesCount(Math.floor(products.length / 9));
}

async function getData() {
  const api_url = `https://******&per_page=9&page=${currentPage}`;
  const req = await fetch(api_url);
  const products = await req.json();
  UpdateProductData(products);
}


Looks like you are trying to use both a state and the URL to determine which page is the current page.
If you want to use the browser back and foward actions to navigate, you shouldn't be using a React state, only use the URL and your buttons should update the URL

You should have only a single source of truth for what page you are on. Here you are using the URL search params, and a local currentPage state, and then sessionStorage on top of that. I think you also have too many side-effects and overloaded functions/handlers/callbacks.
I suspect you don't need the currentPage state, you can read and update the p URLSearchParameter and synchronize to/from sessionStorage.
Suggested Changes:

Only update the p search parameter from sessionStorage if p is not set and there is a stored session value.
prevPage/nextPage only update the URL search params
Too many effects, use a single effect to read the current page and

Fetch data
Fetch page counts/etc
Persist current page to sessionStorage



Example:
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

const [pagesCount, setPagesCount] = useState(0);
const [itemsCount, setItemsCount] = useState(0);
const [productData, UpdateProductData] = useState([]);

// Read current page from search params, fallback to storage
const currentPage = Number(searchParams.get("p")) ?? getCurrentPage();

// Fetch data for the current page
useEffect(() => {
  getData(currentPage);
  calcPagesCount();
  saveCurrentPage(currentPage);
}, [currentPage]);

function prevPage() {
  setSearchParams(searchParams => {
    const p = Number(searchParams.get("p")) || 1;
    searchParams.set("p", Math.max(1, p - 1));
    return searchParams;
  });
}

function nextPage() {
  setSearchParams(searchParams => {
    const p = Number(searchParams.get("p")) || 1;
    searchParams.set("p", Math.min(p + 1, pagesCount));
    return searchParams;
  });
}

function saveCurrentPage(currentPage: number) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("current page", String(currentPage));
}

function getCurrentPage(): number {
  return Number(sessionStorage.getItem("current page") || 1);
}

async function getData(currentPage: number) {
  const api_url = `https://******&per_page=9&page=${currentPage}`;
  const req = await fetch(api_url);
  const products = await req.json();
  UpdateProductData(products);
}


Thanks! Single source of truth being URL search params does work in fixing issue number two, but browser back button still acts the same. If I am at home page and just switching pages back and forward browser button works correctly, but as soon as I get into specific product page it's moves me out of the website on second browser back click.

Ok I correct myself. On Init useEffect function is not needed anymore, that was messing things up. Case closed. Thank you very much!

@DariusMolotokas Welcome, happy to help. Cheers!
